# How to repeatedly add the same element to an array

Tags: java, arrays

How to repeatedly add the same element to an array, I am new beginner in Java, could anyone help me solve this problem

For example,

```
When N = 1
int[] a1 = {1,2,3}

When N = 2
the result is 
a1 = {1,2,3,1,2,3}
```

what's about 2-d array?

```
N is the number of rows
When N = 1
int[][] a1 = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}

When N= 2
a2 = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}
      {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it appears to be a zero-effort requirements dump.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, or to clarify *precisely* where you are having difficulty, this downvote may be retracted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example you provided, it seems to me that you want to repeatedly add the same *element**s*** (plural) into your array a particular N number of times.

Because arrays are fixed in size, you can't declare
`int[] a1 = {1,2,3};`and then attempt to add more elements to it. That is why I recommend you use an ArrayList. Here is an example of how you could create an ArrayList and repeatedly add the same elements to it a set number of times.

```
    // number of times you want to add elements (1, 2, 3)
    int timesToRepeat = 2;

    // your ArrayList instance
    ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // use add() to add the integer elements 1, 2, 3
    a1.add(1);
    a1.add(2);
    a1.add(3);

    // clone a1 so we have a non-changing copy of it when we get to our for loop
    ArrayList<Integer> a1copy = (ArrayList<Integer>) a1.clone();

    // here's where it will take the three elements (1, 2, 3) from a1copy
    // it will repeatedly add them to a1 as many times as you specified
    // you specify this number when setting the int variable timesToRepeat
    for (int i = timesToRepeat; i > 1; --i) {
        a1.addAll(a1copy);

    }

    // print your ArrayList
    System.out.println(a1);
```

You can also create a 2-d ArrayLists and do the same thing by using `addAll()` to add the pattern of elements an N number of times.